# JaCoCo reports zero coverage for mocked method

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, mockito, jacoco, android-instrumentation

I know there are quite a few questions (and answers) for this topic, but I've tried everything I found in SO and other sites and I haven't found a way to make JaCoCo include coverage for Android tests that use Mockito.

My problem:
I want to use JaCoCo to generate code coverage of both Unit Test and Instrumentation Test (androidTest). I'm using Mockito to mock some of the classes. I found a sample in GitHub to use JaCoCo and used it as a starting point.

https://github.com/rafaeltoledo/unified-code-coverage-android

When I run the custom jacocoTestReport task included in that example, the code coverage report is properly generated and code coverage is at 100%. The report includes both unit test and android test. However, that sample is not using Mockito (which I need), so I added the following to app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
 ...
 androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-android:2.10.0'
}
```

I added a very simple Java class called Util at  app/src/main/java/net/rafaeltoledo/coverage/Util.java

```
public class Util {
    public int anIntMethod() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And added the following simple test to the existing android test at app/src/androidTest/java/net/rafaeltoledo/coverage/MainActivityTest.java

```
@Test
public void utilMethod() {
    Util util = Mockito.mock(Util.class);
    Mockito.doReturn(10).when(util).anIntMethod();
    assertThat(util.anIntMethod(), is(10));
}
```

When I run the jacocoTestReport again, code coverage drops to 88% and the report in fact shows the Util class was not covered by my tests, even though I clearly have a test that exercises that class.

(I wanted to add screenshots of the reports but I don't have enough reputation, so here's a link to the [coverage report and execution report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVF27.png) that shows that both tests were in fact executed)

Versions info:
Gradle plug-in: 2.3.3
Jacoco: 0.7.8.201612092310
Android Studio: 2.3.3
Android build tools: 25.0.2

Is this a Jacoco limitation or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> am I doing something wrong?

Let's put aside Android, because there is IMO clearly something wrong with your expectations/understanding about core thing here - mocking:

> even though I clearly have a test that exercises that class.

By

> ```
> @Test
> public void utilMethod() {
>     Util util = Mockito.mock(Util.class);
>     Mockito.doReturn(10).when(util).anIntMethod();
>     assertThat(util.anIntMethod(), is(10));
> }
> ```

you are not testing `anIntMethod`, you are testing something that always returns `10`, no matter what is actually written in `anIntMethod`.

Coverage shows what was executed and hence absolutely correct that it is zero for `anIntMethod` since it is not executed.

Mocking is used to isolate **class under test** from its dependencies, but not to replace it, otherwise you're not testing real code.

Here is an example of proper usage of mocking:

`src/main/java/Util.java`:

```
public class Util {
  int anIntMethod(Dependency d) {
    return d.get();
  }
}
class Dependency {
  int get() {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

`src/test/java/UtilTest.java`:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class UtilTest {
  @Test
  public void utilMethod() {
    Dependency d = Mockito.mock(Dependency.class);
    Mockito.doReturn(10).when(d).get();
    assertEquals(10, new Util().anIntMethod(d));
  }
}
```

`build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "jacoco"

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  testCompile "junit:junit:4.12"
  testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.10.0"
}
```

And after execution of `gradle build jacocoTestReport` coverage is

[image: coverage]

And case of partial mocking:

`src/main/java/Util.java`:

```
public class Util {
  int get() {
    return 0;
  }

  int anIntMethod() {
    return get();
  }
}
```

`src/test/java/UtilTest.java`:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class UtilTest {
  @Test
  public void utilMethod() {
    Util util = Mockito.mock(
      Util.class,
      Mockito.withSettings().defaultAnswer(Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS)
    );
    Mockito.doReturn(10).when(util).get();
    assertEquals(10, util.anIntMethod());
  }
}
```

[image: coverage]

In both cases mocked parts are shown as uncovered and this is correct.

Comment: thanks for the detailed response! My expectations and understanding were clearly wrong.

Comment: Upvote for a very thorough and clear explanation of a very common mistake about mocking!