# Why Spring @Service methods appear with 0% code coverage in JaCoCo?

Tags: spring, testing, junit, mockito, jacoco

These libraries are loaded:

- JUnit 5.3.2
- JaCoCo 0.8.2
- Mockito 2.10.0

Only element "static {...}" appears with 100% coverage. All the rest is at 0%:

[image: JaCoCo report]

The unit test class has annotations `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` and `@AutoConfigureMockMvc`. The service is injected with `@Mock`.

```
doReturn(actual).when(service).get(param);
when(service.get(param)).thenReturn(actual);

expected = service.get(param);
verify(service, times(1)).get(param);

assertEquals(expected, actual);
assertEquals(actual, expected);
```

My `ServiceImpl` class is red when I click any method. It extends an abstract class. Jackson's `ObjectMapper` is red, and also the entire lines within the methods. For example:

```
public CustomReturnObject get(final CustomParamObject paramObject) {
    try {
        return retryTemplate.execute(status -> {
            String json = repository.get(paramObject);
            CustomReturnObject returnObject = json2CustomObject(json, paramObject);

            if (returnObject == null) {
                returnObject = new CustomReturnObject();
                returnObject.setId(paramObject.getId());
            }

            return returnObject;
        });
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similarly to https://stackoverflow.com/a/46614216/244993 let's put aside Spring, because there is IMO clearly something wrong with your expectations/understanding about core thing here - mocking.

By

> ```
> doReturn(actual).when(service).get(param);
> expected = service.get(param);
> verify(service, times(1)).get(param);
> assertEquals(expected, actual);
> ```

you are not testing `get` method, you are testing something that always returns `actual`, no matter what is actually written in `get`, because in this case it is not executed.

Here is [**complete** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as a proof:

`src/main/java/hello/GreetingService.java`:

```
package hello;

class GreetingService {

  Object get(Object param) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
  }

}
```

`src/test/java/hello/GreetingServiceTest.java`:

```
package hello;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.doReturn;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class GreetingServiceTest {

  @Mock
  public GreetingService service;

  @Test
  void test() {
    Object param = new Object();
    Object actual = new Object();

    doReturn(actual).when(service).get(param);
    Object expected = service.get(param);
    verify(service, Mockito.times(1)).get(param);
    assertEquals(expected, actual);
  }

}
```

`build.gradle` :

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:2.23.4'
}
```

Real method `get` throws `UnsupportedOperationException`, however above test succeeds, so real method was not executed. As another way to proof that `get` not executed: put a breakpoint into it and execute test in debug mode from IDE - breakpoint won't be reached.

Coverage shows what was really executed and hence absolutely correct that it is zero for methods that are not executed.