# Method not covered during JUnit code coverage (Eclemma code coverage testing); It says "All 2 branches missed"

Tags: unit-testing, junit, code-coverage, eclemma

I was wondering if anyone could help me, my method is not covered during code coverage testing even though I mocked it in the test class.
This is my method in the main class `DeviceService.java` which I am trying to mock in test class:

```
public List<String> getDeviceList(String device) {
        if (StringUtils.hasText(device)) {
            List <String> deviceList = Stream.of(device.split("[, ]")).collect(Collectors.toList());
            return deviceList ;
        }
        return null;
   }
```

This is my test class method in `DeviceServiceTest.java`. I mocked the`getDeviceList` in test class like this, in two separate test methods:

```
@Mock 
private DeviceService parameters;
when(parameters.getDeviceList(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(Arrays.asList("Smartphone"));
when(parameters.getDeviceList(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(new ArrayList<>());
```

Comment: Hello! Maybe I am missing something, but it is not clear to me what are you trying to do. If you want to test your method (and have it covered), use your `DeviceService` as sut instead of mock.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JaCoCo + Mockito + Android tests: Zero coverage reported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46517471/jacoco-mockito-android-tests-zero-coverage-reported)